# Haskell: polymorphic function is throwing type errors

Tags: haskell

I have the following case. As can be seen, I have a less than class that takes ints and returns a bool. I am trying to create a Polyeq class that can take either ints or bools (or maybe even strings) and evaluates to see if they are equal and return a bool:

```
class Symantics repr where
    int :: Int  -> repr Int            
    add :: repr Int  -> repr Int -> repr Int
    bool :: Bool -> repr Bool

newtype R a = R{unR :: a}

instance Symantics R where
    int x     = R x
    add e1 e2 = R $ unR e1 + unR e2
    bool b    = R b

    
class Lth repr where
    lth :: repr Int -> repr Int -> repr Bool 

instance Lth R where
    lth e1 e2 = R $ unR e1 < unR e2  
    
 
class Polyeq a where
    polyeq :: a -> a -> Bool  
    
instance Polyeq R where
    polyeq e1 e2 = R $ unR e1 == unR e2
```

---

I get the following error when compiling:

error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘R Bool’

• In the expression: R $ unR e1 == unR e2

  In an equation for ‘polyeq’: polyeq e1 e2 = R $ unR e1 == unR e2

  In the instance declaration for ‘Polyeq Int’
```

error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘R a0’ with actual type ‘Int’

• In the first argument of ‘unR’, namely ‘e1’

  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘unR e1’

  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘unR e1 == unR e2’
```

error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘R a0’ with actual type ‘Int’

• In the first argument of ‘unR’, namely ‘e2’

  In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘unR e2’

  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘unR e1 == unR e2’
```

### Failed, modules loaded: none.

updated code: now throwing

error:

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘R’

  Expected a type, but ‘R’ has kind ‘* -> *’

• In the first argument of ‘Polyeq’, namely ‘R’

  In the instance declaration for ‘Polyeq R’
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of `Polyeq R` has two problems: first, its parameter `R` has the wrong kind (the class specifies `*`, but `R` has kind `* -> *`), and second the implementation of method `polyeq` returns `R` while its signature calls for `Bool`

The shortest way to fix is to provide the expected kind and expected implementation:

```
instance Polyeq (R a) where
    polyeq e1 e2 = unR e1 == unR e2
```

---

But I suspect what you really meant was for the class to be defined on a variable of kind `* -> *`, similar to the `Symantics` class and its method `add`:

```
class Polyeq repr where
    polyeq :: Eq a => repr a -> repr a -> repr Bool  
    
instance Polyeq R where
    polyeq e1 e2 = R $ unR e1 == unR e2
```

---

I must also note that customarily these things are achieved via an `Applicative` instance and [`liftA2`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.20/base-4.13.0.0/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2).

If you define an `Applicative` instance for `R`:

```
instance Functor R where
    fmap f (R x) = R $ f x

instance Applicative R where
    pure = R
    liftA2 f (R a) (R b) = R $ f a b
```

Then all definitions in your classes degrade into:

```
int = pure
bool = pure
add = liftA2 (+)
lth = liftA2 (<)
polyeq = liftA2 (==)
```

Comment: "But I suspect what you really meant was for the class to be defined on a variable of kind" Yes this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In that case it really escapes me how you were able to define `add`, yet stumbled on `polyeq`

Comment: Can you please explain what Eq a => means. I am very new to haskell and functional programming

Comment: It means that whatever `a` turns out to be, it has to have an instance of the `Eq` class. That class is where the `==` function comes from, so you couldn't use it would such instance.

Comment: I see. If I wanted to create a polymorphic class that was not part of the Eq class, for example to find the first of a pair. Would it be:     class Fst1 repr where
    fst1 :: repr a -> repr a -> repr a     
 ---followed by---
instance Fst1 R where
    fst1 [x,x2] = R $ unR x    ?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense: the type signature specifies two parameters, but the implementation has one parameter of list type. Also, `R $ unR x` is the same as just `x`